# I have removed the `Cookies`'s token and csrftoken, why still have them?

Tags: javascript, cookies, token

I have a

This is my key code:

```
        var that = this

        // clear sessionid, csrftoken
        that.$Cookies.remove('sessionid');
        that.$Cookies.remove('csrftoken');

        // login
        that.$http.post(Urls.users.login(), params).then((response) => {

          setTimeout(loading, 0)

          that.$Cookies.set('token', response.data.key);

          that.get_user_info()

        }).catch((response) => {
            debugger
            setTimeout(loading, 0)

          }
        )
```

in the `main.js` I configure like this, so the the component I can use the `this.$Cookies`:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, "$Cookies", { value: Cookies })
```

You see I have removed the `token` and `csrftoken`, but when I access the login api, there still has the `token` and `csrftoken` in the request:

[image]

Whether I clear the token and csrftoken in the `this.$Cookies` it did not clear success essentially.

Answer (score 0):

I am so interested in this question. Why I have deleted some cookie, but when I send a request, the cookie is Still in header?

So I find you use `js-cookie`, and I go to the [github](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and get this:

Delete a cookie valid to the path of the current page:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { path: '' });
Cookies.remove('name'); // fail!
Cookies.remove('name', { path: '' }); // removed!
```

IMPORTANT! When deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path and domain attributes that were used to set the cookie, unless you're relying on the default attributes.

Hope can help you~

Comment: what do you mean of the `domain attributes `?

Comment: its no use, I also checked, the this.$Cookies() do not shows the `csrftoken` and `sessionid`. when access the API, seems it will take up automatically.